# How can I add a string to the last line in multiline EditText, Matlab?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, android-edittext

I often use this way to add a string to the last line in multiline editText.

Example: The before editText: (handles.txtLine)

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

and i want to add string "line 4" to it. So i do:

```
msg = get(handles.txtLine,'string');
msg_i = sprintf('\nline 4');
msg = [msg msg_i];
set(handles.txtLine,'string',msg)
```

Result:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

Are there other methods to do the same function?

Answer (score 0):

The `String` property of a multiline edit control can be set in three ways:

1. a multiline character array, e.g. `txt1= ['line 1'; 'line 2']`. Here `txt1` has size 2x6.
2. a single line character array containing newline characters, e.g. `txt2= sprintf('line 1\nline 2')`. Here `txt2` has size 1x13.
3. a cell array of strings, e.g. `txt3 = {'line 1', 'line 2'}`

You would add or remove text from the string in each case in different ways, and each method has advantages and disadvantages.

1 is usually inconvenient, as all your lines have to have exactly the same length, or be padded with spaces. But if that's the case, then it's easy to add or remove lines.

2 (basically the way you're doing it now) is also usually less convenient, as while it's easy to append lines, it's less easy to remove them from the middle unless you parse the string looking for newlines. But if you only ever need to add lines, it's probably fine.

I would modify the way you're using `sprintf` and then concatenating:

`msg = sprintf('%s\n%s', msg, 'line 4');`

is a simpler and more flexible syntax.

Your general method of getting, modifying and setting the `String` property is fine, although if you wanted you could combine it all into one starement, such as:

`set(handles.txtLine, 'String', sprintf('%s\n%s', get(handles.txtLine, 'String'), 'line4'))`

3 would typically be the most convenient, as long as you're comfortable with cell arrays. Each line can be whatever you like, and it's easy to add or remove items.

Comment: Hi. I'm newbie, so I can't present my problem to you until 4/25/2014 12:25:55 AM. This is my topic in Mathworks http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/126940-matlab-gui-how-can-i-add-a-string-to-the-last-line-in-multiline-edittext. Can you help me resolve it! Thanks you very much.